# Create a Sencha Touch app using the command line tools - Beginner

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

To generate a Sencha Touch project from the command line tools, i followed the following steps as described in many forums and also in the official Sencha touch doc. But it couldn't find the generate keyword.

Steps :

```
Navigate to the touch-2.2.1 SDK folder which is located at /Application/XAMPP/htdocs/touch-2.2.1/

sencha generate app MyWeb ../MyWeb/myweb
```

But, it failed to create a path at this specified location.

Can someone guide me with the steps to solve this?

Comment: Check if you have enough rights to write on directory, and if not on Windows - right click the folder and under 'security' tab assign the rights to the users and it should work

Answer (score 4):

Use following steps:

1. Go to directory where you have put Sencha Touch folder.
   e.g. On Linux, if you have put it in Document/sencha/sencha_touch2.2.1 go to that directory using cd Documents/sencha/sencha_touch2.2.1.
2. Use command to generate app : 
   sencha generate app appname destination directory path/your app name.
   e.g. You want to create app in www directory,use
   sencha generate app myapp /var/www/myapp1

here myapp is app name and myapp1 is a directory in www that contains all application structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/sencha-touch-2-sdk generate app MyApp /path/to/www/myapp
```

Here,

1. /path/to/sencha-touch-2-sdk is path to your Sencha Touch library folder
2. /path/to/www/myapp is the path to the app

Comment: So according to my question i should write it as follows; sencha -sdk /Application/XAMPP/htdocs/touch-2.2.1/ generate app MYAPP ../MYAPP But it doesn't get created.

Comment: I think there's a bug in Sencha touch. It doesn't get created.

Comment: No warnings as such. It just doesn't create the project structure

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps it may be helpful
1> Download Sencha CMD
2> Install Sencha CMD for that you required java installed on machine set environmental path of java.
3> After successful installation sencha cmd set sencha cmd environmental path.
4> Now open terminal/commandprompt type sencha if everything work fine it shows sencha help and sencha installed cmd version.
5> Now download sencha touch extract sencha touch folder in any directory you want.
6> After that go to that sencha touch folder from terminla or command prompt.
7> Then type following command for generating new app.
   sencha generate app app_name /path/to-set-application/app_name
8> Open Webkit browser like chrome or safari type your folder path like
    localhost/app_name
  It Work !

Comment: I get the following warning when i type `sencha` in terminal. `[WARN] The current working directory (/Users/MyName) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder. Running in backwards compatible mode.`

Comment: and the sencha command version is `Sencha Command v2.0.0 Beta 3`

Comment: Hi Sharon, go to your sencha command folder like /user/myname/senchasdk and try to generate app sencha command.Or you export sencha sdk path, and why you using sencha command V2.0.0 Beta try to use latest sencha sdk v3.1.2.342 :)